# Why aren't my threads start at the same time? Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have variable number of threads which are used for parallel downloading. I used this,

```
for(int i = 0; i< sth; i++){
       thrList.add(new myThread (parameters));
       thrList.get(i).start();
       thrList.get(i).join();
```

}

I don't know why but they wait for each other to complete. When using threads, I am supposed get mixed print outs, since right then there are several threads running that code. However, when I print them out, they are always in order and one thread waits for the previous one to finish first. I only want them to join the main thread, not wait for each other. I noticed that when I measured time while downloading in parallel.

How can I fix this? Why are they doing it in order?

In my .java,
there is MyThread class with run and there is Downloader class with static methods and variables. Would they be the cause of this? The static methods and variables?

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much better off using an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// pool is reusable

List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
for(int i=0;i<sth;i++) callables.add(new MyCallable(i));
for(Future<Void> futures : es.invokeAll(callables))
    futures.get();
```

Comment: This one won't wait for each other right? Mine still does even after seperating join() loop.

Comment: I don't know what MyRunnable is with parameter i. Is it my myThread?

Comment: it says "The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (List<Runnable>)"

Comment: Thank you Ada, changing Runnable to Callable. If you want to wait for the results/completion. adding code for that too.

Answer (score 11):

you are creating a thread, waiting for it to complete (join), creating a new thread, waiting for it to complete (join) etcetera.

you should read the java documentation regarding threads to know what most method do:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: ohw I got it. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Ada: get rid of the call to `join()`

Comment: I did and made another for loop where I joined but it didn't change. Still it downloads serially, not parellel.

Comment: Are any of the static methods on your `Downloader` class `synchronized`? That could be the cause of the problem. Otherwise we need to know more about the implementations of both `Downloader` and `MyThread`.

Comment: we cannot give you the solution to why it still don't work. multithreading and synchronization is a difficult subject with a lot of subtleties, so read a lot about it and try to improve your program while learning. it seems to me that you are trying to do to much in one unit of work (`Downloader` and/or `MyThread`), so try to split them up in smaller units.

Answer (score 3):

Easy. The problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i< sth; i++){
       thrList.add(new myThread (parameters));
       thrList.get(i).start(); // problem
       thrList.get(i).join();  // problem
}
```

Specifically, each iteration of the loop is creating a thread, starting it then waiting for it to join again. Which is why they're running in serial.

What you need to do is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< sth; i++){
       thrList.add(new myThread (parameters));
       thrList.get(i).start();
}

for(int i = 0; i< sth; i++){
       thrList.get(i).join();
}
```

Which will go through the process of launching all the threads then it will loop through each thread and wait for it to exit.

Comment: they still wait for each other don't know why

Comment: @ada It depends what the threads are doing too, of course. If the threads are accessing a blocking resource (one they have to wait for and access one at a time) this could be a problem. I don't know without seeing more. Others have pointed out documentation and the Executor service which does look much neater. Mine is simply the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Also, hello downvoter, care to comment on what exactly is wrong with this? I don't see anything problematic and my demo involving sleeps and system.outs works fine in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You start a thread and immediately join into it, thus rendering the whole threading useless, as you are waiting for the completion of the thread.

```
   thrList.get(i).start();
   thrList.get(i).join();
```

You should use a synchronized queue where the spawned threads themselves grab the parameters from, wait until the queue is empty and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The join method waits for the chosen thread to die. The current thread (the one doing the loop that fires off the events) is waiting for the thread you just started to die before going around again and starting the next one.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get System.getCurrentThread().join().Should I call it in run? Will it make the child threads to finish and join the main one?

Comment: I used it but they didn't join. When I needed only the main thread, I printed out the number of active threads and it was 5. How can I join them?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. You need a reference to the main thread rather than calling System.getCurrentThread().join(), and it wouldn't really do what you are expecting anyway. Use an ExecutorService (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), it's a lot easier, and exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried that but it told me that I can't use Runnable with that. My deadline finishes 1.5 hours later and I am panicked :)

Comment: Join just causes the current thread to wait for the thread represented by the thread object join was invoked on to die. It's not really doing anything. If you want to avoid ExecutorService, you can use a CountDownLatch instead (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), plugged with the number of downloader threads you have. When one completes, countdown the latch. Eventually the latch will go to 0 and signal the awaiting thread (your main thread), which will continue...

Answer (score 0):

Just do 2 loops, first start them all, then join them all.

Answer (score 0):

For what I interpret from your question, since is not clearly stated, is that you have several downloader threads and want to synchronize them. In that case you need to use an external structure such as a [CountdownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). A CountdownLatch is a "synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes." Think of it as a counter that decreases every time a downloader thread finishes, when the countdown reaches 0 then all threads should be done with their work.

Let's see some code taken directly from the official javadoc of CountdownLatch:

```
 CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
 CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(N);

 for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // create and start threads
     new Thread(new Worker(startSignal, doneSignal)).start(); 

 startSignal.countDown(); // Threads are waiting for startSignal's counter to reach 0 and start their work, more or less at the same time
 doneSignal.await(); // The current thread will sleep at this point until all worker threads have each one called doneSignal.countDown() and the countdown reaches 0

 joinDownloadedPieces(); // At this point is safe to assume that your threads have finished and you can go on with anything else
```

Your worker Runnable/Thread class would look something like this:

```
public void run() {
    startSignal.await(); // Wait until given the go

    downloadSomething();

    doneSignal.countDown(); // Notify that we are done here
}
```

I say is safe to assume since you will have to deal with InterruptedExceptions that can wake your thread while waiting, before all of them finish. For more information I recommend you take a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. It's IMHO one of the best gems of Java and the documentation is thorough and often more than enough to understand the function of each structure.

Comment: I don't know, this seems like overkill for something as simple as parallel downloading. Then again using the `ExecutorService` would be a good idea to void creating and destroying many threads in a long-running application.

Comment: @Neil I agree, Executors should be preferred over using Threads directly. However Latches are used for threads synchronization, not to manage their life cycle.

Comment: Yes, but there doesn't appear to be any requirement from the OP to synchronize the starting point of the threads, i.e. each thread can start as soon as it's ready. Therefore you could reduce this to just one Latch.